# Query to count the distinct words of all values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table "post" :

```
id            Post
-----------------------------
1             Post Testing
2             Post Checking
3             My First Post
4             My first Post Check
```

I need to count the number of distinct words in all the values for the `Post` column.

Is there any way to get the following results using a single query?

```
post       count
------------------
Post         4
Testing      1
checking     1
My           2
first        2
check        1
```

Comment: you want this functionality only in mysql or you want to use any server side languages like PHP?

Comment: I need to use in PHP

Comment: then please change the question. and the answer which is given by @gordan seems work without the PHP also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in an easy way.  If you know the maximum number of words, then you can do something like this:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(p.post, ' ', n.n), ' ', -1) as word,
       count(*)
from post p join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
     ) n
     on length(p.post) - length(replace(p.post, ' ', '')) < n.n
group by word;
```

Note that this only works if the words are separated by single spaces.  If you have a separate dictionary of all possibly words, you can also use that, something like:

```
select d.word, count(p.id)
from dictionary d left join
     posts p
     on concat(' ', p.post, ' ') like concat(' %', d.word, ' %')
group by d.word
```

Comment: I set up the exaxmple data in Mysql 5.7 mentioned by the OP. Testing this query, the word & count results don't match the data (i.e. "Post" should be 4, "My" & "first" are missing etc): Check 1
Checking 3
Post 2
Testing 3

Answer (score 0):

[You can use a FULLTEXT index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-innodb-ft-index-table-table.html).

First add a FULLTEXT index to your column like:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ft_post
    ON post(Post);
```

Then flush the index to disk using optimize table:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_optimize_fulltext_only=ON;

OPTIMIZE TABLE post;

SET GLOBAL innodb_optimize_fulltext_only=OFF;
```

Set the aux table:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_ft_aux_table = '{yourDb}/post';
```

And now you may simply select for word and word counts like:

```
SELECT word, doc_count FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE;
```