# How to get the number of same words of a specific MySQL column?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

i need to make a flask template that counts every repeated word in a database column  in this time named **titlecol** and show it in a div, kinda similar to this example: https://github.com/piyush335/Flask-WordCount. But it needs to load automatically when i open a template in the web browser without filling a form like that example.

Here is the code:

```
# app.py
**Dashboard**
@app.route('/dashboard')
@is_logged_in
def dashboard():

    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

    result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE author = %s", [session['username']])

    articles = cur.fetchall()

    if result > 0:
        return render_template('dashboard.html', articles=articles)
    else:
        msg = 'No articles found'
        return render_template('dashboard.html', msg=msg)

    cur.close()


**Article**
@app.route('/article/<string:id>/')
@is_logged_in
def article(id):

    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()


    result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = %s", [id])

    article = cur.fetchone()

    return render_template('article.html', article=article)

# dashboard.html
                    <table id="registr" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                        <th>Title Name</th>   
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                            {% for article in articles %}
                            <tr>
                        <td>{{article.titlecol}}</td>
                        <td><a href="article/{{article.id}}" class="btn btn-icon btn-info btn-round pull-right"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a></td>
                        <td><a href="edit_article/{{article.id}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-icon btn-round pull-right"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i></td>
                        <td>
                          <form action="{{url_for('delete_article', id=article.id)}}" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                            <input type="submit" value="X" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon btn-round" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">
                          </form>
                        </td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858847/query-to-count-the-distinct-words-of-all-values-in-a-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it sql, group by some column and count the distinct of the required column.

Comment: Hello,i did the sql in phpmyadmin and works                                                                                               SELECT COUNT(id), titlecol
FROM articles
GROUP BY titlecol;       ...but i don't know how to make it work in app.py i tried using: result = cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(id),titlecol FROM articles GROUP BY titlecol = %s", [article]) im a newbie in flask and databases.

Comment: Are you able to run a query and get the result in flask, make sure the connection is setup correctly.

Comment: I added in app.py result = cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(id),titlecol FROM articles GROUP BY titlecol") and it only shows in dashboard.html  data from the titlecol column but not the COUNT(id) result data. if i delete the comma after (id) shows show the number of many rows are repeated but not the words it self. I don't know what I'm forgetting

Comment: Go through documentation for flask, usually you use fetchone or something similar not execute.